# How do I show or hide file extensions of multiple files on a Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line

Variations of this question almost always describe a tedious one-at-a-time "Get Info" process to check or uncheck "hide extension", OR to use a hammer approach by using Finder -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Show all file extensions. I've found a way to deal with batches of files all at once, using Terminal.app with a single command line.

You need the Developer utility called "SetFile". If you have that in /Developer/Tools, then make an alias (ln -s) of it on your $PATH, or add the path to it to your $PATH. Now, every file has "attributes", which you can see with the companion utility "GetFileInfo". These are letters, either UPPER or lower case. "E" and "e" indicate "hide" or "show" the extension. You can easily switch between them with SetFile. But you can also feed a set of file names into SetFile, and do them ALL with one command line. Here's a simple example:

I have a bunch of .doc (MS Word) documents, some showing the extension, some hiding the extension. I what ALL of them to show the extension.  Assume they are in some folder. Navigate to the folder, and do this:

```
 ls -1 *.doc | tr " " "?" | xargs -L1 SetFile -a
```

The -1 gives every filename in your folder with the desired extension. The "tr" command translates blanks in the file names to "?", meaning a single match character so the names don't have blanks in them. Then "xargs -L1" feeds each name to "SetFile -a e" which says to "show" the extension for that file. If it already is being shown, it stays that way.

SetFile may not like names with "?" in them, but it certainly doesn't like names with blanks unless the file-argument to SetFile is in quotes. Unfortunately, "xargs" will break up names with blanks into separate executions of SetFile, which is even worse.

Lastly, if you want to "hide" all extensions, use "SetFile -a E" instead.

Comment: Good tip, but aren't "tips" supposed to be handled differently than Questions on this site?  I thought this site was for Questions only?

Comment: Please reformat your question so that it is only a question and place your 'tip' as the answer and mark it as so. This helps others see that this question already has an answer.